# retrieve specific field from a previous date

Tags: sql, database, date

The following information is currently present in a database.

```
ID -- Company --- Current Value ---- Date
1 -- company1 ------- 12 --------- 25th March 2010
2 -- company1 ------- 17 --------- 25th March 2011
3 -- company2 ------- 65 --------- 23rd April 2011
4 -- company1 ------- 45 --------- 25th March 2012
5 -- company2 ------- 34 --------- 23rd April 2012
```

Is there some way that I can calculate the field to find the value for each company's previous year ?

```
ID -- Company --- Current Value --- Last Year Value ---- Date
1 -- company1 ------- 12 ---------------- 0 --------- 25th March 2010
2 -- company1 ------- 17 --------------- 12 --------- 25th March 2011
3 -- company2 ------- 65 ---------------- 0 --------- 23rd April 2011
4 -- company1 ------- 45 --------------- 17 --------- 25th March 2012
5 -- company2 ------- 34 --------------- 65 --------- 23rd April 2012
```

I have tried many solutions including searching this website but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your table appears to have dates one year apart exactly, it can be simply done by left joining itself.

```
SELECT a.ID, 
    a.Company, 
    a.CurrentValue, 
    ISNULL(b.CurrentValue, 0) AS 'LastYearValue',
    a.Date
FROM dbo.Table a
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table b ON a.Company = b.Company AND b.Date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, a.Date)
```

Comment: i'm currently trying this but getting an error on line 4 with the null statement